# Can't get Tilestache working on Apache (mod_wsgi)

Tags: apache, tilestache

Trying to get a tileserver running on Ubuntu 14.04 with TileStache and Apache.

No problem running the TileStache development server (tilestache-server.py) or the uWSGI example from the API docs:

```
uwsgi --http :8080 --eval 'import TileStache; application = TileStache.WSGITileServer("/etc/TileStache/tilestache.cfg")'
```

However, I can't get it to serve tiles with mod_wsgi through Apache (2.4.7). Followed the instructions here: https://github.com/TileStache/TileStache/issues/67:

Created wsgi file (/var/www/tilestache/tilestache.wsgi, owned by Apache with 0750 permissions) containing:

```
import os, TileStache
application = TileStache.WSGITileServer('/etc/TileStache/tilestache.cfg')
```

Following those instructions, added:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /tilestache /var/www/tilestache/tilestache.wsgi
```

To my Apache config. Navigating to that alias on any of the defined virtualhosts returns a 403 - Forbidden.

I've also tried replacing that line with the following, but returns the same 403:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess tilestache
WSGIProcessGroup tilestache
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias /tilestache /var/www/tilestache/tilestache.wsgi
```

I've also tried moving those lines inside of a virtualhost, with the same result.

Note: I've changed the tilestache.cfg to use the test/simple cache (not actually caching anything).